# How to determine the value of the parameter t for certain radian values on the unit circle with rational parameterization

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So I drew a unit circle in geogebra and I can slide the point $T$ up and down along the y-axis to play around with the rational parameterization.

[image]

So, from what I gathered (feel free to point out any flaws in my understanding here) point $A$ is at $(-1,0)$ and connects to $T$ which is at $(0,t)$ where $t$ is some arbitrary rational number (parameter).  This gives a Cartesian formula for the line of $y= tx+t = t(x+1)$ (so the parameter $t$ is both the slope/gradient and the y-intercept of the line).

Then knowing the unit circle is $x^2+y^2=1$ the system of equations can be solved to find the intersection points of the line and the unit circle one of which is point $B$, which working it out comes out to be:

$B = \left( \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \dfrac{2t}{1+t^2} \right)$

(That is except for the other solution which is the point (-1,0), which is odd in itself as sliding $t$ toward positive or negative infinity the parameterization tends to this point).

Anyways, all that aside, I was told this approach was somehow superior to the "normal" parameterization involving the transcendental functions, e.g. $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ because the rational parameterization gives exact answers while the transcendental gives approximations.

Yet, I'm not sure how I would determine the value $t$ if I was asked to find the point at say $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ on the unit circle.  Also, as $B$ approaches $A$ wouldn't $t$ become so large that it wouldn't be practical to write out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the point on the unit circle with angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$ occurs where the line $y=x$ intersects the circle. This line can be parametrized by $(t,t)$. So we need the intersection of the lines parametrized by $(t,t)$ and 
$$
\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{1+t^2} \right)
$$
where $(t,t)$ intersects the unit circle--the point $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$. So just set the corresponding parts of the parametrization equal and solve the equations. However, notice that you should have an irrational value of $t$ because we know the point on the unit circle with angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is the point $(\cos \pi/4,\sin \pi/4)=\left(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}\right)$. So although
$$
\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{1+t^2} \right)
$$
may be the 'rational' parametrization of the unit circle, we still need irrational $t$ values to get the irrational points on the unit circle--using the rational values of $t$ is not enough. Because then if $t$ is rational, $t^2$ and $2t$ is rational, so the parametrization is rational. Therefore, the only points you get out of it are rational. So to get the irrational values on the unit circle, $t$ necessarily need be irrational.

However, this parametrization is still very useful! It is 'easier' to calculate points on the unit circle if we are forced to do it by hand (as it avoids the transcendental functions). Of course, this is somewhat a matter of 'opinion' as with Taylor Series for $\sin$ and $\cos$ it would be equivalent hand calculation procedures (but there we would have to use multiples of $\pi$'s for our angles and that would be the messy part).

More importantly, this parametrization let's us find all the rational points on the unit circle. Indeed, this type of parametrization plays an important role in the theory of elliptic curves. See the first chapter of Silverman and Tate's [Rational Points on Elliptic Curves](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_14?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=rational%20points%20on%20elliptic%20curves&sprefix=rational%20point,aps,284&rh=i%3aaps,k%3arational%20points%20on%20elliptic%20curves) for a demonstration of this.

EDIT: I forgot about your question about what happens at $B$ approaches $A$. Notice as that happens, we get closer and closer to the tangent line of the circle at $A$. This line is easy to figure out and the rational point there is obviously $A=(-1,0)$. What value of $t$ would we need to get that? Well, we would need $t=\pm \infty$ but that's not in the reals! So we can't get it, but we know it's there. In order to get the point $A$, we need to include $\infty$ in the reals. We call this the extended real numbers. However, it is more fruitful just to think of this as a point at infinity, so that our parametrization can actually get all the points on the circle. This is the idea of [Projective Geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry). Indeed, in the Silverman book I referenced, they discuss this immediately with the concept I talked about, see [projective line's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_line) to get a rough idea of what they discuss there. However, the first chapter of Silverman's book is quite good! Though, you could see the first chapter and chapter 2.3 of [this](http://people.cs.nctu.edu.tw/~rjchen/ECC2012S/Elliptic%20Curves%20Number%20Theory%20And%20Cryptography%202n.pdf)  instead if you do not have access to Silverman's book to get the idea as well. But this is a bit beyond what you have asked.

And to be specific, you want
$$
\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{2t}{1+t^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
which is $t=\sqrt{2}-1$.